# What is the shortest URL that can store the order of 78 items?

Tags: url, logic

I'm trying to figure out how to have the shortest URL possible that stores the order of 78 cards. The best I could do was using 78 different characters, each representing a different card.

Is there a formula that could do a better job for me?

Cheers,

Comment: You can store these values in two 64bit INT values

Comment: how many states for each of the 78 cards?

Answer (score 1):

You might try a *compression* format? It essentially will find patterns in your char data and group them.

For example:
say your 78 char format has a `8273400000234270000` then you might see `827340r5234270r4` instead. It gets a lot more complex than that and I'm willing to bet there's much smoother/better solutions on the web. [Here's a google search for String Compression.](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=string%20compression)

Comment: Thank you Jackson, I have never heard of string compression so that was very helpful. Cheers! It seems that since URLs are limited to ASCII characters, the "compressed" version could be even longer than the original. It seems like a 78 character URL is my best bet.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too. Perhaps you could generate both and just use whichever is shortest? That's more work, but it depends on how bad you want it :)